# WPF DataGrid vertical sizing

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, contentcontrol, wpf-4.0

I want to place a DataGrid inside a HeaderedContentControl but the the DataGrid does not get a vertical Scrollbar. It appears to be sized to hold all rows at once, the bottom disappearing from view.

If I place the same DataGrid in a Border elelemnt I do get the behaviour I want.

I have reduced it to this minimal example:

```
<Grid>
    <HeaderedContentControl  Margin="10,10,10,161" >
        <HeaderedContentControl.Header >test</HeaderedContentControl.Header>

        <!-- I want it Here but then no Vertical Scroll-->
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllData}"                      
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"  />
    </HeaderedContentControl>

    <Border Margin="10,169,10,10">                                
        <!--Here it does scroll -->
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllData}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"  />
    </Border>                      
</Grid>
```

A few notes:

- I couldn't get it to work using  HeaderedContentControl.VerticalContentAlignment
- this problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444871/wpf-datagrid-inside-accordion-height-issue) but I think I've broadened it a bit and that there is a better answer.
- using a ScrollViewer around the DataGrid is not a solution because it scrolls the header out of sight.
- I am using WPF4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because the default template for `HeaderedContentControl` is using a `StackPanel` to show its contents. Since the `StackPanel` takes the size of its children, the `DataGrid` expands its height to have every of its items shown on the screen without scrollbars. The display is then cropped due to the size of the `HeaderedContentControl`.

Changing the template to use a `Grid` or a `DockPanel` solves this problem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
        <DockPanel>
          <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" ContentSource="Header" />
          <ContentPresenter />
        </DockPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```